# How to count records in SQL

Tags: sql

> Edit: Schema taken/extrapolated from comment below

```
create table #employees 
(
    Emp_ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Dept_ID int,
);

create table #departments
(
    Dept_ID int,
    Dept_Name varchar(50)
);
```

How do I count the number of employees from table employees that work in each department in table departments and include all departments that have no employees working in them.

Comment: and where is your sql ??

Comment: Is `COUNT(*)` not working for you?

Comment: It's only counting departments that have employees in them

Comment: Do you expect us to be able to answer this? You have provided nothing in the way of details.

Comment: Salma, welcome to the community. I would recommend (and embracing) reading the legend Jon Skeet's [post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on writing the perfect question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

This problem is quite simple to solve. The steps would be as follows:

1. Join the **Departments** table to the **Employees** table on the `Dept_ID` column.
2. `SELECT` the `Dept_ID` and `Count()` and `GROUP BY` the `Dept_ID` field.
3. In order to return **Departments** without employees you need to `LEFT JOIN` this aggregation to the **Departments** table on the `Dept_ID` column.
4. In order to return the value of **0** for departments without employees, use the `ISNULL()` function.

Please see the below sample script using your schema. Note that this script is written in T-SQL, as you did not mention your server type.

```
create table #employees 
(
    Emp_ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    Dept_ID int,
);

create table #departments
(
    Dept_ID int,
    Dept_Name varchar(50)
);

insert into #employees
select 1, 'Pim', 1
union all
select 2, 'Salma', 2;

insert into #departments
select 1, 'IT'
union all
select 2, 'Marketing'
union all
select 3, 'Design'

select
    d1.Dept_Name
    ,isnull(d2.EmployeeCount, 0) as EmployeeCount
from
    #departments d1
left join
    (
        select
            d.Dept_ID
            ,count(e.Dept_ID) as EmployeeCount
        from
            #departments d
        join
            #employees e
            on e.Dept_ID = d.Dept_ID
        group by
            d.Dept_ID
    )
    d2
    on d2.Dept_ID = d1.Dept_ID

drop table #employees
drop table #departments
```

Comment: @SalmaOsama No problem whatsoever. If the solution I provided has helped solve your problem I would greatly appreciate it if you could "Accept" my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have supplied no data please try below and see if this works for you

Create the tables, I don't know if this is similar to your table structure

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_EMPLOYEES (Empl_Name nvarchar(20), Dept nvarchar(15))

CREATE TABLE tbl_DEPARTMENT (Dept nvarchar(15))
```

Populate these tables

```
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('James', 'Finance')
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('Tim', 'HR')
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('Sally', 'Finance')
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('Bob', 'Sales')
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('Sam', 'HR')
INSERT INTO tbl_EMPLOYEES Values ('James', 'Finance')

INSERT INTO tbl_DEPARTMENT Values ('Finance')
INSERT INTO tbl_DEPARTMENT Values ('HR')
INSERT INTO tbl_DEPARTMENT Values ('Sales')
INSERT INTO tbl_DEPARTMENT Values ('IT')
```

This query will give you the number of people in each department

```
SELECT Dept, Count(Dept) AS Count
FROM
    (
        SELECT Dept 
        FROM tbl_EMPLOYEES
         ) AS Blah_Blah
GROUP BY Dept
```

Comment: I have table Employees containing Name,Dept_ID and table Department containing Dep_Name, Dept_ID and I want to count the number of employees in each departments. And if department 1 has 0 employees then it should outcome its name and 0